# convert the list to Json array

Tags: javascript

I am getting data from backend in the below format:

```
[{
    patientId=2501, 
    uniqueId=PID140, 
    firstName=bairava, 
    middleName=, 
    lastName=surya, 
    emailAddress=**1717259005##@noemailaddress.com, 
    birthday=2016-01-07 00:00:00.0, 
    portraitId=0, 
    race=, 
    companyId=10253, 
    ssn=123-54-7678, 
    ethnicity=0, 
    bloodGroup=0, 
    gender=1, 
    patientLanguageId=,         
    folderId=53501, 
    activationReason=, 
    deactivationReason=, 
    patientStatus=Active, 
    activationRequest=false, 
    cashPayment=true
}]
```

How can I iterate and get each details individually?

Comment: Is that the actual format of the response? If so it's not valid JSON.

Comment: use JSON.parse(LIST)

Comment: @AbbasGaliyakot given that the format isn't even close to valid JSON, that would just throw more errors.

Comment: Error:JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data...so just tell me how i can access it in efficent manner.

Comment: `I am getting data from backend ` do you mean as `string`?

Comment: var msglis='<%=message.getMatchedPatientlist()%>'; this the way am fetching the type is List<Patient>

Comment: it completely different please check mine question.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to explain. Just read the code and try to understand.

The way is to convert this `string` to a JavaScript structure object.

```js
// The output html from the server
var msglis='[{ patientId=2501, uniqueId=PID140, firstName=bairava, middleName=, lastName=surya, emailAddress=**1717259005##@noemailaddress.com, birthday=2016-01-07 00:00:00.0, portraitId=0, race=, companyId=10253, ssn=123-54-7678, ethnicity=0, bloodGroup=0, gender=1, patientLanguageId=, folderId=53501, activationReason=, deactivationReason=, patientStatus=Active, activationRequest=false, cashPayment=true }, { patientId=2506, uniqueId=PID140, firstName=bairava, middleName=, lastName=surya, emailAddress=**1717259005##@noemailaddress.com, birthday=2016-01-07 00:00:00.0, portraitId=0, race=, companyId=10253, ssn=123-54-7678, ethnicity=0, bloodGroup=0, gender=1, patientLanguageId=, folderId=53501, activationReason=, deactivationReason=, patientStatus=Active, activationRequest=false, cashPayment=true }]';

var arr = msglis.replace(/=/g, ':').replace(/:.*?[,}]/g, function(a, b, c) {
  console.log(c);
  var comma = a.indexOf(',') > -1;
  var val = a.replace(':', '').replace(',', '');
  
  if (/^\d+$/g.test(val)) {
    return a;
  }
  else {
    return ':"' + val + '"' + (comma ? ',' : '}');
  }
});


var obj = eval(arr);
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

You can see the `regex` in action [here](http://scriptular.com/#%7B%7B.*%3F%7D%7D%7C%7C%7C%7Cg%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%22%3Cdiv%20class%3D%5C%22zuzLogo%5C%22%3E%7B%7Blogo%7D%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E%7B%7Btabs%7D%7D%22%5D)

Comment: thanks alot for your reply  doesnot work if it has  more than one objects....

Comment: can you provide me code that works for multiple objects..

Comment: thanks alot man!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: My pleasure ;) That's was challenging ;) If it does do the job, please accept this answer so it will help to other people.

Comment: when am passing it to a function --'<input type="button" value="one" onclick="showMatchedPatient('+obj+')">' it shows error as SyntaxError: missing ] after element list so please help it out ASAP.

Comment: `obj` is the object from the snippet? I guess that you add this input dynamically with JavaScript. If so, you can't do this like this. You need to convert the `object` to `string` first using `JSON.stringify` like this: `<input type="button" value="one" onclick="showMatchedPatient('+ JSON.stringify(obj)+')">`

Comment: when i do this i get  SyntaxError: invalid property id..so my goal i need to pass the msglis variable to the function and i wil use your code to convert it to the string object so help me out to send inside function.

Comment: Are you generate this button with JavaScript?